# Dynamic Pivot result into fixed table (SSIS or SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I got a stored procedure, which gives me data by a dynamic pivot and I want to insert this data into a table, which has all possible columns, the dynamic pivot could produce.

Example:

The dynamic pivot stored procedure gives the following table as result:

```
Property_A  Property_C
----------------------
Value_A     Value_A
Value_B     Value_C
...
```

On another run the same SP may produce

```
Property_A  Property_B
----------------------
Value_D     Value_A
...
```

Whatever it returns, the result should be put into a table like this

```
Property_A  Property_B  Property_C
----------------------------------
Value_A     NULL        Value_A
Value_B     NULL        Value_C
Value_D     Value_A     NULL
```

and so on.

How can I achieve this via SQL (MS SQL Server) or better via SSIS?

Thanks in advance,

tombom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky to handle if the calling process doesn't know what the columns are in the results.  To insert into a table (permanent or temporary), the number of columns inserted must match the number of columns to insert.

Here's how you would insert the results of the SP to a table.  Notice that you don't have to include all columns in the table.  However, in my example, usp_MakeDate_1 returns two of three columns (Property_A, Property_C) and usp_MakeData_2 returns a set of two different columns (Property_A, Property_B).

```
INSERT INTO MyResults (Property_A, Property_C)
EXEC dbo.usp_MakeData_1

INSERT INTO MyResults (Property_A, Property_B)
EXEC dbo.usp_MakeData_2
```

You'll find that SSIS is even more restrictive when it comes to dynamic SQL.  For the most part, your outputs and inputs must be known at design time.

Comment: Oh, I see. You insert the result into the table inside the stored procedure. SSIS boiled my brain, so I didn't think of this solution. In my case acceptable. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
INTO
  MyNewTable
FROM
  TempTableProducedByStoredProc
```

Comment: This does't work, neither your way, nor with "... FROM EXEC myStoredProcedure". Incorrect syntax. And the problem is, that I don't know yet, how to store the stored procedure result in a temp table. I'm about to learn about UDF right now. Maybe this helps.